# What is the average number of words necessary to read classical Chinese?

Tags: vocabulary, classical-chinese

I heard classical Chinese had a limited amount of vocabularies compared to modern Chinese. 
How many words one has to learn in order to acquire average reading abilities, disregarding the grammar?

Comment: Not many, several hundreds I guess, if the "average" refers to the quantity that Chinese middle/high school students should learn. However even for native speakers, classical Chinese is difficult because the functional words have too many meanings. It would be a good start to read the novels after Ming Dynasty -- they are closer to modern Chinese , therefore easy to follow.

Comment: The problem in learning to read Classical Chinese is much less acquiring the character-vocabulary than it is learning the grammar and learning to gauge the meaning of very terse sentences.

Answer (score 3):

According to [二十五史的字数是多少？](http://zhidao.baidu.com/question/41331955.html), most of the classics contain five to six thousand unique characters. 《辽史》(Liao history) contains as few as 4071; 《清史》(Qing history) contains as many as 8080.

《史记》93 BC contains 5122 unique characters;

《汉书》83 AD, 5833 unique characters;

《新唐书》1060 AD, 6346字;

《清史》1927 AD, 8080字.

According to [this site](http://baike.baidu.com/view/1712.htm#6), the first dictionary 《说文解字》which was finished in 121 AD contains 9353 characters; another one which was created in 1716 AD contains 47035 characters.

Han dynasty's《说文解字》 finished in 121 AD, contains 9353;

Song dynasty's《集韵》(1034AD) contains 53525;

Qing dynasty's《康熙字典》(1716 AD) contains 47035;

《中华字海》published in 1994 AD contains 85000.